# Other than the opcache what can require php-fpm to be restarted to see changes?

Tags: php, fpm

I have opcache setup as follows:

```
; When disabled, you must reset the OPcache manually or restart the
; webserver for changes to the filesystem to take effect.
opcache.validate_timestamps=1

; How often (in seconds) to check file timestamps for changes to the shared
; memory storage allocation. ("1" means validate once per second, but only
; once per request. "0" means always validate)
opcache.revalidate_freq=0
```

When deploying changes, I find that I still need to restart php-fpm to see them.

What other settings should I be investigating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`opcache.revalidate_path`

Check the value of this setting. If it is set to `0`, OPcache will not check file timestamps for changes at all, which could explain why you are not seeing the changes. Make sure it is set to `1`.

You could also verify `opcache.max_accelerated_files`, `opcache.validate_permission` & `opcache.fast_shutdown`

Comment: `revalidate_path` to `1` looks to have done the trick of those options. Thanks!